# No matter vs whoever picks up the phone

Tags: grammar

A native English language user just corrected my sentence construction but I believe mine is the correct one:

(An agent giving a suggestion to a customer)

> "I give you your order number, so that **no** **matter** **who** picks up the phone when you call back, your record can be pulled up faster.(native English language user)

Vs.

> "I give you your order number, so **whoever** picks up the phone when you call back, your record can be pulled up faster.(mine)

I feel like the first sentence is a bit off. Please correct.

Comment: Both are acceptable in any register.

Comment: I find "I give you your order number" significantly more awkward and attention-getting than either of the two alternatives you asked about. Say "I **will** (or I'll) give you your order number..." and either "whoever" or "no matter who." Both are fine.

Comment: @TypeIA, you are correct,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That native English language user sounds like he was being extra harsh that day. Unless he was your writing instructor, and he was correcting your essay or exam, I don't think it was necessary to correct that sentence.

However, if you really think about the grammar involved, he does have a point. The second sentence is the one that is a bit off (a very tiny bit, though).

"**Whoever**" is a noun, and "**whoever picks up the phone**" is a noun phrase. So just sticking a noun phrase in the middle of a sentence with no predicate attached to it isn't quite right, even though it *sounds* OK to me, and as a native speaker I might easily say it without being corrected by others.

On the other hand, in the first sentence, the "**no matter who** ..." construction is idiomatically an adverbial phrase, and when you stick it into that same sentence (in the same place), it functions as a modifier of the whole clause, "**your record can be pulled up faster.**" This usage sounds fine too, and I think it is more in keeping with formal grammar rules.